# Video player in Xamarin Forms is gone when minimized and resumed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have implemented a video player in xamarin forms to play as a **background video** for my login screen. The video successfully loads at start and plays without sound and loops(as configured). But the problem is when I **minimize the app and resume again**, then **the video is gone** and I **can't even play it back** like `video.play if paused or stopped`

The links I tried are as follows

1. http://makanda.io/how-to-create-a-background-video-in-xamarin-forms/ (I tried this link first)
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/ (then completely replaced with this)

Both links work as desired except the issue which is the same in both links.

What I have tried to solve the issue?

1. I tried resuming the video as `if(videoPlayer.Status == Renderers.VideoStatus.Paused) videoPlayer.Play()` inside my `OnAppearing()` method. But it doesn't work
2. I am currently trying to dynamically load the video from code behind inside a stack layout. But I don't know how to set the video source from code behind. I am doing it as follows

---

```
string source = "";
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.iOS:
        source = "Videos/walkthroughvideo9_16.mp4";
        break;
    case Device.Android:
        source = "walkthroughvideo9_16.mp4";
        break;
    default:
        source = "walkthroughvideo9_16.mp4";
        break;
}

VideoPlayer video = new VideoPlayer()
{
    Source = (UriVideoSource)source
};
```

> An error says, cannot convert string to UriVideoSource

AN HELP LINK:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView

Seems like the video view does not maintain its state when the app goes into the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a timer as a workaround to resume the video which pauses when the app goes into sleep mode.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    shouldTimerRun = true;

    Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            if (videoPlayer.Status == VideoStatus.Paused)
            {
                //videoPlayer.TimeToEnd = timeSpan;
                videoPlayer.Position = timeSpan;
                videoPlayer.Play();
            }
        });
        return shouldTimerRun;
    });
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    shouldTimerRun = false;
    timeSpan = videoPlayer.Position;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accpet your answer. It will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I am currently trying to dynamically load the video from code behind inside a stack layout. But I don't know how to set the video source from code behind. I am doing it as follows

I notice that your path is from local Resource, you can use the following code to load the video. If your path is an URL, you can use  `videoPlayer.Source = VideoSource.FromUri(source);` to load it.

```
  var videoPlayer=new VideoPlayer();

            string source = "";
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    source = "Videos/iOSApiVideo.mp4";
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    source = "AndroidApiVideo.mp4";
                    break;
                default:
                    source = "AndroidApiVideo.mp4";
                    break;
            }
            videoPlayer.Source = VideoSource.FromResource(source);
```

> I tried resuming the video as if(videoPlayer.Status == Renderers.VideoStatus.Paused) videoPlayer.Play() inside my OnAppearing() method. But it doesn't work

Here is my running demo result, when I am back to my application, it works. I also achieve the *seek to the previous time span* function as well.

[image]

Here is my demo.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kpYbMV5mA3UdbGD7r6tLv1S2ix7AwM5B/view?usp=sharing

Comment: if above answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Hi @Leon. I tried your code. But still the same issue.

Comment: @Thameem Please post your demo.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NUYMqG8krlAZFukfdeCw4wPxUCQmL7ZV/view?usp=sharing       This is my code dude.

Comment: when I run your project in the drive, it is working as expected. cant figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: My code running normally, but you used same code in your project, it cannot get correct result, am I right?

Comment: yes. ur right. i deployed your app in my mobile and checked. the video is resuming as expected. but the same code copied in my proj and deployed, the video is stopping or is gone after resuming from sleep mode

Comment: I think i got the problem, the video is just normally pausing after resuming from the sleep mode. so playing the video again from pause mode is not working inside the page.OnAppearing metho. i tried the videoPlayer.Play method inside the carousel view on currentitem changed event and the video is playing fine. so the OnAppearing method is not working when app resumes.

Comment: I tried the OnResume event in the App class but not successfull. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, that's important, my xamarin forms nuget package version is 4.8.0.1269, I running at the Android 9.0, my target framework is Android 9.0, you can make same settings as my project, if it works.

Comment: Mine is also Xamarin 4.8. But i cannot target the version 9.0 as hereafter we have to mandatorily target version 10 inorder to upload the app to playstore as per the new Policy by google

Comment: Aaaah got the solution but a workaround only. I put a timer which keeps checking if the video is paused, if yes then it resumes that video. The page.OnAppearing method only occurs when we navigate back and forth the pages, not when resuming from sleep mode. So that was the reason for the video not resuming back inside the page.OnAppearing method. Thanks for helping me out